# Why is my nested query statement not working?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, subquery

The following is the prompt i'm trying to answer:

Write the nested statement to list the first and last names of those employees who have the same job as Larry Smith.

The following is the employee table columns:

EMPLOYEE(Emp_Num, Emp_Lname, Emp_Fname,Emp_Initial, Emp_HireDate, Job_Code)

The following is my nested query:

```
select emp_fname, emp_lname
from EMPLOYEE
where job_code =
(select job_code
from employee
where emp_fname = 'larry'
and emp_lname = 'smith');
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: What goes wrong? Is there an error message?

Comment: Your query looks fine to me. I would prefer writing the query as a join or with an `EXISTS` subquery, but this is perfectly valid. The only problem is if the subquery returns more than one row. In that case, it would be not just my preference but *actually better* to switch to a real `JOIN`. Queries that use `IN` with subqueries that use `IN` with subqueries that use `IN` are maddeningly difficult to understand and modify, and are completely unnecessary! Expert SQL writers do not write queries this way.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, the reason why it wasn't working is because I had deleted some tuples in which 'Larry Smith' was one of them. Also, I was told you can always do a nested query rather than a join because it uses less resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `IN` not `=`:

```
select emp_fname, emp_lname
from EMPLOYEE
where job_code IN
  (select job_code
   from employee
   where emp_fname = 'larry'
     and emp_lname = 'smith');
```

The reason being that you are comparing a value to the set returned by the subquery.

Comment: Although the query still works with the "=", I am upvoting you because my professor always stresses "IN".  The problem was that I forgot I had deleted some tuples in which "Larry Smith" was one of them.  Thank you for your answer though.  Lets say that Larry Smith was still in there.  How would I return the results with out "larry Smith" in the result?

Comment: Use "NOT IN" as the operator in front of the subquery.

Comment: What @PieterGeerkens said.

Comment: Saying "You should be using IN not =" is silly. If you explicitly expect the subquery to return only one row, then it is *better* to use `=` because then if it returns two rows you will get an error about multiple rows. It is much worse to silently get the **wrong data** of possibly two job codes from the unexpected condition of there being, say, *two* Larry Smiths in the database.

Comment: @ErikE: If one tuple is to be expected for a given `first_name, last_name` - then a database unique constraint should enforce this, not the SQL query that will discover this at runtime. `IN` will work for any scenario that `=` will, and will also not break when multiple rows are detected. Moreover, using `=` will not necessarily work with other RDBMS's (notably MySQL and PostgreSQL) and has no real upside. In truth, this answer assumes the failure was due to multiple results in the subquery (which wasn't the case here), but I do believe that `IN` is superior to `=` in any case.

Comment: A `UNIQUE` constraint on `FirstName, LastName` is even more silly. That is exactly what I was talking about! Writing queries so they fail when expectations are violated is better practice than writing queries so they don't ever throw errors. There is an inherent logical flaw in the OP's example query, and simply fixing it cosmetically with `IN` is just as bad as, say, fixing a query with `DISTINCT`. Routinely using `IN` is, in my mind, a mistake. See my comment on the OP about this subquery practice as well--I think it's sloppy and often is part of SQL newbie disease.

Comment: @ErikE: Please clarify why you think that a unique constraint to enforce business logic is 'silly'.

Comment: Unique constraints to enforce business logic are silly when the "business logic" they enforce is illogical. People don't have unique first and last names. We can't reject a perfectly good employee because he has the same first and last name as an existing employee! Use his employee ID or something that it is logical on which to have a `UNIQUE` constraint. Then, using `=` is safe. I admire the goal of writing standards-compliant SQL, but I even more admire code that clearly communicates its intent, and using `IN` when you know there can be only one is a kind of "coding deception".

Comment: @ErikE: If the problem is in the business logic itself (as you proposed), then using a JOIN (as you proposed) isn't going to help either. The OP was suggesting a valid (albeit, naive) query that should _not_ break regardless of the data present. If you are concerned that the query may be the wrong one, you should double check it given the current business logic. You certainly should _not_ rely on a query structure throwing a run-time exception to discover this. Ideally, unit tests should do that for you. As such, `=` provides no benefit over `IN`, which was my point.

Comment: Do you object to this, too? `where job_code = (select top 1 job_code from employee where emp_fname = 'larry' and emp_lname = 'smith');`? I reject the idea that queries should never break. The concept of early failure is an important one. See [fail-fast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast). It is better to think in terms of the *whole system* rather than just following blindly the idea that "queries should never possibly fail". Failure is good when *not failing* is worse! Pulling too many rows could be a very costly "failure".